# Can I get the type or fingerprint of an encrypted SSH private key using JSch without decrypting it?

Tags: android, kotlin, jsch

Can I get the **type** (`RSA`, `DSA`, `ECDSA`, `ED25519`...) or the **fingerprint** of a passphrase protected private SSH key without decrypting it with **JSch** *(like you can in Linux with `ssh-keygen -l -f <key_file>`)*?

I'm writing an Android app and **JSch** is pretty much the only lib that I managed to get to work with Android so it has to be done with **JSch** or manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`KeyPair.load`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/KeyPair.html#load-com.jcraft.jsch.JSch-byte:A-byte:A-) to load the key.

And then [`KeyPair.getKeyType`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/KeyPair.html#getKeyType--) and [`KeyPair.getFingerPrint`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/KeyPair.html#getFingerPrint--) to access its properties.

```
JSch jSch = new JSch();
KeyPair keypair = KeyPair.load(jSch, filename);
System.out.println(keypair.getKeyType());
System.out.println(keypair.getFingerPrint(jSch));
```

Answer (score 1):

[Martin Prikryl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850848/martin-prikryl)'s answer is correct however I asked the question because I was getting `IllegalStateException` with the message  `encrypted key has not been decrypted yet.` when I called `getKeyType()` so I thought that you can't get info about locked keys. After some more trial and error I found out that the problem was specific to the fork of **JSch** I use (`com.github.mwiede:jsch:0.2.1`) that adds support for `ED25519` keys and the problem is specific to `ED25519` keys. I solved my problem this way:

```java
private static int getKeyType(Path keyFilePath) {
    try {
        Path keyFile = keyFilePath;
        final byte[] key = Files.readAllBytes(keyFile);
        final JSch jSch = new JSch();
        final KeyPair keyPair = KeyPair.load(jSch, key, null);
        return keyPair.getKeyType();
    } catch (final IOException | JSchException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        return 0; // 0 is the key type of ERROR defined in the KeyPair class
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        if (e.getMessage().equals("encrypted key has not been decrypted yet."))
            return 5; // 5 is the key type of ED25519 defined in the KeyPair class
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}
```